# Как разместить рекламу после 2 абзаца?

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var s1 = document.createElement('script');
s1.src='http://fejla.com/555555555555';
s1.type = 'text/javascript';
$("p:eq(2)").after(s1);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Ну и правильно... Проверьте ссылку-скрипт, ошибка должно быть в ней.

Comment: забавляет всегда эта помесь нативного js и тут же jquery.